# Is it possible to combine 5 functions into 1 function that triggers the 5 actions at once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am archiving data from one page with 5 different button clicks that activate 5 different functions.  Can I combine the 5 functions into one function and only click once to activate all 5 actions?

Comment: Although, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about `function sample() { yourFunction1(); yourFunction2(); yourFunction3(); yourFunction4(); yourFunction5(); }`? By this, when you run `sample()`, those 5 functions can be run. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Consider posting it as a answer. Simple answers are more valuable than complicated ones.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I agree with your comment. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to run 5 functions by one call.

In this case, I would like to suggest the following sample script.

```js
function yourFunction1() {
  // do something
}

function yourFunction2() {
  // do something
}

function yourFunction3() {
  // do something
}

function yourFunction4() {
  // do something
}

function yourFunction5() {
  // do something
}

function sample() {
  yourFunction1();
  yourFunction2();
  yourFunction3();
  yourFunction4();
  yourFunction5();
}
```

- In this sample, it supposes that your 5 functions are `yourFunction1` to `yourFunction5`.
- By `sample` function, when this function is run, your 5 functions are run in order.
- If it is required to rearrange the order of executions, please modify it.

Comment: love this break down...  You all are the best!  sooo appreciative

Comment: @Tillthen BigHeart Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `love this break down... You all are the best! sooo appreciative` and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it?